# How to create a customized scoring function in scikit-learn for scoring a set of instances based on their individual properties?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, decision-tree, scoring

I'm trying to perform `GridSearchCV` to optimize hyperparameters of my classifier, this should be done by optimizing a custom scoring-function. The problem is, that the scoring-function is assigned on a certain cost, that is different each instance (the cost is also a feature of each instance). Like shown in the example below, another array `test_amt` is needed that holds the cost of each instance (in addition to the 'normal' scoring function that just gets `y` and `y_pred`.

```
    def calculate_costs(y_test, y_test_pred, test_amt):
        cost = 0

        for i in range(1, len(y_test)):
            y = y_test.iloc[i]
            y_pred = y_test_pred.iloc[i]
            x_amt = test_amt.iloc[i]

            if y == 0 and y_pred == 0:
                cost -= x_amt * 1.1
            elif y == 0 and y_pred == 1:
                cost += x_amt
            elif y == 1 and y_pred == 0:
                cost += x_amt * 1.1
            elif y == 1 and y_pred == 1:
                cost += 0
            else:
                print("ERROR! No cost could be assigned to the instance: " + str(i))
        return cost
```

When I call this function after training with the three arrays, it perfectly calculates the total cost that results from a model. However integrating this into *GridSearchCV* is difficult, because the scoring function only expects two parameters. While there is the possibility to pass additional *kwargs* to the [scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html), I have no clue on how to pass a subset that is dependent on the split that *GridSearchCV* is currently working on.

What I have thought of / tried so far:

1. Wrapping the whole pipeline in a class with a globally stored `pandas.Series` object that stores the cost of each instance with an index. Then, it would theoretically be possible to reference the cost of an instance by calling it with the same index. Unfortunately, this does not work as scikit-learn transforms everything into a numpy array.

   ```
   def calculate_costs_class(y_test, y_test_pred):
       cost = 0
       for index, _ in y_test.iteritems():
           y = y_test.loc[index]
           y_pred = y_test_pred.loc[index]
           x_amt = self.test_amt.loc[index]

           if y == 0 and y_pred == 0:
               cost += (x_amt * (-1)) + 5 + (x_amt * 0.1)  # -revenue, +shipping, +fees
           elif y == 0 and y_pred == 1:
               cost += x_amt  # +revenue
           elif y == 1 and y_pred == 0:
               cost += x_amt + 5 + (x_amt * 0.1) + 5  # +revenue, +shipping, +fees, +charge cost
           elif y == 1 and y_pred == 1:
               cost += 0  # nothing
           else:
               print("ERROR! No cost could be assigned to the instance: " + str(index))
       return cost
   ```
2. Creating a custom *PseudoInt* class, that is the data type of the label, which inherits all properties from *int* but is also able to store the cost of an instance (while retaining all its properties for applying logical operations). While even this would work outside of Scikit Learn, the *check_classification_targets* method in scikit learn raises a *ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'* error.

   ```
   class PseudoInt(int):
       def __new__(cls, x, cost, *args, **kwargs):
           instance = int.__new__(cls, x, *args, **kwargs)
           instance.cost = cost
           return instance
   ```
3. I haven't tried but thought of: Since the cost is also a feature in the instance set `X`, it is also available in the `__call__` method of `_PredictScorer(_BaseScorer)` class in Scikit's `scorer.py`. If I reprogram the call function to also pass the cost array as a subset of `X` to the `score_func` I would also have the cost.
4. Or: I could just implement everything myself.

**Is there an "easier" solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem by going the path of the 2nd proposed answer: Passing a PseudoInteger to Scikit-Learn that has all the same properties as a normal integer when compared or done mathematical operations with. However, it also acts as a wrapper for the int, and instance variables (such as the cost of an instance) can also be stored. As already stated in the question, this causes Scikit-learn to recognize that the values inside the passed label array are in fact of type *object* rather than *int*. So I just replaced the test in the *type_of_target(y)* method of Scikit-Learn's *multiclass.py* in line 273 to return *'binary'* even though it doesn't pass the test. So that Scikit-Learn just treats the whole problem (as it should be) like a binary classification problem. So line 269-273 in the *type_of_target(y)* method in *multiclass.py* now looks like:

```
# Invalid inputs
if y.ndim > 2 or (y.dtype == object and len(y) and
                  not isinstance(y.flat[0], string_types)):
    # return 'unknown'  # [[[1, 2]]] or [obj_1] and not ["label_1"]
    return 'binary' # Sneaky, modified to force binary classification.
```

My code then looks like this:

```
import sklearn
import sklearn.model_selection
import sklearn.base
import sklearn.metrics
import numpy as np
import sklearn.tree
import sklearn.feature_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import make_scorer


class PseudoInt(int):
    # Behaves like an integer, but is able to store instance variables
    pass


def grid_search(x, y_normal, x_amounts):
    # Change the label set to a np array containing pseudo ints with the costs associated with the instances
    y = np.empty(len(y_normal), dtype=PseudoInt)
    for index, value in y_normal.iteritems():
        new_int = PseudoInt(value)
        new_int.cost = x_amounts.loc[index]  # Here the cost is added to the label
        y[index] = new_int

    # Normal train test split
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

    # Classifier
    clf = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

    # Custom scorer with the cost function below (lower cost is better)
    cost_scorer = make_scorer(cost_function, greater_is_better=False)  # Custom cost function (Lower cost is better)

    # Define pipeline
    pipe = Pipeline([('clf', clf)])

    # Grid search grid with any hyper parameters or other settings
    param_grid = [
        {'sfs__estimator__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']}
    ]

    # Grid search and pass the custom scorer function
    gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe,
                      param_grid=param_grid,
                      scoring=cost_scorer,
                      n_jobs=1,
                      cv=5,
                      refit=True)

    # run grid search and refit with best hyper parameters
    gs = gs.fit(x_train.as_matrix(), y_train)
    print("Best Parameters: " + str(gs.best_params_))
    print('Best Accuracy: ' + str(gs.best_score_))

    # Predict with retrained model (with best parameters)
    y_test_pred = gs.predict(x_test.as_matrix())

    # Get scores (also cost score)
    get_scores(y_test, y_test_pred)


def get_scores(y_test, y_test_pred):
    print("Getting scores")

    print("SCORES")
    precision = sklearn.metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
    recall = sklearn.metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
    f1_score = sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
    accuracy = sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
    print("Precision      " + str(precision))
    print("Recall         " + str(recall))
    print("Accuracy       " + str(accuracy))
    print("F1_Score       " + str(f1_score))

    print("COST")
    cost = cost_function(y_test, y_test_pred)
    print("Cost Savings   " + str(-cost))

    print("CONFUSION MATRIX")
    cnf_matrix = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test_pred)
    cnf_matrix = cnf_matrix.astype('float') / cnf_matrix.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    print(cnf_matrix)


def cost_function(y_test, y_test_pred):
    """
    Calculates total cost based on TP, FP, TN, FN and the cost of a certain instance
    :param y_test: Has to be an array of PseudoInts containing the cost of each instance
    :param y_test_pred: Any array of PseudoInts or ints
    :return: Returns total cost
    """
    cost = 0

    for index in range(len(y_test)):
        # print(index)
        y = y_test[index]
        y_pred = y_test_pred[index]
        x_amt = y.cost

        if y == 0 and y_pred == 0:
            cost -= x_amt # Reducing cot by x_amt
        elif y == 0 and y_pred == 1:
            cost += x_amt  # Wrong classification adds cost
        elif y == 1 and y_pred == 0:
            cost += x_amt + 5 # Wrong classification adds cost and fee
        elif y == 1 and y_pred == 1:
            cost += 0  # No cost
        else:
            raise ValueError("No cost could be assigned to the instance: " + str(index))

    # print("Cost: " + str(cost))
    return cost
```

### UPDATE

Instead of changing the files in the package directly (which is kind of dirty), I now added to the first import lines of my project:

```
import sklearn.utils.multiclass

def return_binary(y):
    return "binary"

sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target = return_binary
```

This overwrites the *type_of_tartget(y)* method in *sklearn.utils.multiclass* to always return *binary*. Note that his has to be in front of all the other sklearn-imports.